# How should I start to talk to my kids about G-d?

Tags: children-parenting, chinuch-education

How should I start to talk to my kids about G-d?

How do I explain that there is a G-d in the first place, what or whom G-d is, the importance of having Him in their lives etc. The importance or meaning of keeping the Torah etc. Without them thinking it is a fairytale or just fantasy. I would really like them to get to feel and understand that His existence is a fact; something we know rather than something we just believe to be true.

Comment: The simple answer is one doesnt! A child doesnt have to think about it. The less the better. Yes teach him to daven, he doesnt have to understand what he is saying. It will come to him by itself, better than it being knocked into him.

Comment: @interested Yeah but what if the child comes to you and says: “What is this G-d you talk about?” or “How do I know that there is such a thing as G-d?” or “How do I know He’s real if I can’t see, touch or hear Him?” or “Why should I personally do all these things written in this book?, what is it good for?” etc. What if the chid asks why others don’t believe nor keep the Torah. Growing up in a non-Jewish environment can make it quite hard with all these atheists or other religions surrounding a child. If it’s the child who’s looking for answers, where does one starts?

Comment: A child doesnt have to know about G-d. He doesnt even have to know he exists and certainly not talk about him. Most religions anyway believe in some type of a G-d. No child needs to look for answers unless he has questions which he shouldnt have. He doesnt have to know why you do things just that you do them. And if you do them sincerely @levi your child will do them without questioning them. What do you do if a child asks about sex and is too young to be told. The same here. Like I wrote the less one talks the better.

Comment: https://animaamin.org/news/